# Extensions Ubuntu Dock and Ubuntu Appindicators not working after upgrade to 19.04

Tags: gnome-shell, ubuntu-dock, gnome-shell-extension, 19.04

I was using the Ubuntu Dock and Ubuntu Appindicators with Gnome Desktop without any trouble in previous versions of Ubuntu.

After upgrading to 19.04 it is apparent that I am using a generic dock which has a different look to the Ubuntu Dock which is working on another 19.04 computer. On the Extensions tab of Gnome Tweaks, Ubuntu Dock has a greyed out selector button next to a "!" (warning) icon. The button for Appindicators does not have this and can be toggled on and off, but Appindicators only worked briefly on one occasion when I did this.

There is no Dock tab in Settings. [see update below]

I also need to add, that since this upgrade I have to launch the Desktop via the startx command in tty, but this is not a major concern for me (details in an earlier post). [see update below]

I attempted to install ubuntu-dock again with both apt and Gnome Software but neither application could locate its package.

Is there a way to get these extensions working again?

Update:  After posting this I ran

```
sudo apt install gnome-session gnome
```

but this did not appear to change anything.  I then installed lightdm (humble apologies to the GNOME team), and this has fixed the abovementioned issue where I needed to  to login via tty and launch the GUI with the startx command.

Since performing these two actions Ubuntu Appindicators appears to be working reliably and the Dock tab has been restored to Settings, but Ubuntu Dock is still non-functional.